# Does good grammar offend?

Tags: conditionals, subjunctive-mood

I'm not a grammar nazi in my native language, and SURELY nor in the language I learn (English). And I think, when a person is expressing thoughts, he or she shouldn't think about grammatical structures, moods, syntax etc., but about WHAT he/she's really saying. That's what I do in my own language. But when I communicate with an English-speaker, I can't help thinking of it. Because I haven't started thinking in English yet.

Situation 1.
I am chatting with somebody on the Internet, and this person writes something like "Oh your funny", and keeps writing *your* instead of *you're*. So when I respond, I write "You're funny too". Wouldn't it make me look like I want to reproach this person?

Situation 2. 
I am talking to a person who's just said "If I was ... ". And the moment when I need to say the sentence with Conditional 2 is coming, so should I say "If I were" (just because I like it and was taught so)? Will he/she think, "Oh look who's talking, wants to make himself look smart".

P. S. Yes, I know that nowadays both variants are correct, but as far as I'm not the native speaker, they're the same to me. And I guess they're not the same to you...

Comment: You can comfort yourself that at least in speech, there are no spelling mistakes. :)  I cannot possibly over-recommend [this exquisite, even eloquent advice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7E-aoXLZGY) on the very matter you raise.  It should be required reading for everyone on ELU.

Comment: I feel something insincere in your two last sentences :-)))))))

Comment: My close limit is reached for today, but this appears to be off topic because it is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

Unless *you* make a point of it most people won't even notice that you've written or said something different.

It's true that people who are sensitive about their grammar might be abashed, just as people who are sticklers for 'correct' grammar may be annoyed if you use an expression they regard as 'incorrect'. But ordinary intercourse provides both of these groups so many opportunities to take offense that you may safely assume they have grown thick skins. If they have not, it is really their problem, not yours.

Comment: Any native speaker who is "sensitive about their grammar" deserves any abashing they encounter. That kind of ignorant oversensitivity to irrelevant details is like obsessing over putting a heart instead of a dot over your lower-case i's and j's. Don't worry about them, just say what you have to say and let them bear the scorn they heap on themselves. They'll survive. Anyway, they wouldn't do it if they didn't enjoy it.

Comment: Yes, but some of whose are sensitive about grammar are in a position to offer employment or grant entry to courses of study. And they may immediately reject any applicants who write 'would of' instead of 'would have' or 'it's' when it needs to be 'its'.

Comment: @JohnLawler Your advice immediately brought to mind [Stephen Fry’s famous anti-pendantry dressing-down](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7E-aoXLZGY). If anyone less well-spoken than Fry had said as much, it could have been taken as an unhealthy rant or even a tirade. But the passion of Fry’s expression here is like a gust of fresh air in a poisonously musty old room whose denizens have lost sight of how just nasty a place they’ve made for themselves and those around them.

Comment: @Shoe: Anybody that deranged would be a bad boss to work for; better off not soliciting or accepting offers from them.

Comment: I am with Steven Pinker here. In his recent book _The Sense of Style_ he states: _If readers can see that a writer cares about consistency and accuracy in her prose, they can be reassured that the writer cares about conduct they cannot see so easily_. I don't regard it as deranged that a potential employer would reject someone who had failed to ensure that their letter of application contained no errors of spelling or punctuation. whether through insouciance or ignorance.

Comment: @Shoe Yes: every speech community sets its own standards of grammaticality.

Answer (score 1):

I am refreshed to find that someone is as annoyed as I am about "your" vs "you're" and "if I was" vs "if I were"!

Truth is, when I see bad grammar I cringe.  But I find myself doing it, too, from time to time.  In fact, this answer may contain some bad grammar!  I don't know if starting a sentence with "Truth is," is ungrammatical.  Perhaps I should have used the definite article?  "The truth is", perhaps?  And I know I have occasionally typed "your" when I should have typed "you're".  I guess I am human, after all.

I'll tell you what I do: unless there's a compelling reason to make a point of it, I ignore other people's grammar foibles.  Sure, go ahead and use "you're" when they use "your" -- be a good example! -- but don't forget that the primary point of grammar is *communication*.  Communication can actually be impeded by pedantry about grammar, and then it becomes counterproductive.

Comment: By the way, I am so chuffed with myself about having attained the lordly reputation of 5,000+ !!!  I have been striving for this day for months.

Answer (score 0):

A new kind of unspoken, text-only pidgin-English (an *e-pidgin*) is being forged by millions of people typing online and texting with their thumbs. Many of these typists are native speakers. They are often marginally literate.

It's an odd thing that here in the US we don't consider math teachers snobs when they point out the decline in numeracy among US students, but we regard English teachers  as pedants when they point out the decline in literacy. If a free press is crucial in a democracy, so are literacy and numeracy.

So, is it better to take a "when not in Rome" approach and use the pidgin oneself?  Or to communicate as a person does who has read a few books? I suppose the answer depends on what your [sic] trying to accomplish online.